# swift:Assign which device send data via multipeer

Tags: ios, swift, multiplayer, multipeer-connectivity

We are writing an iOS application with Swift 4. This app is working with multipeer connectivity. If one player is sending data/images, we want to identify from which device the data/images were sent.

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeerpeerID: MCPeerID) {
    if DataManager.string == false {
        let toSaveArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as! [Int]
        peers.append(peerID)
        print(peers)
    NSLog("Peer \(peerID) has sent message \(toSaveArray)")
    DataManager.speicher1 = toSaveArray



    }else if DataManager.string == true {
        let toSaveString = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as! String
        NSLog("Peer \(peerID) has sent message \(toSaveString)")
        DataManager.speicher2 = toSaveString
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some details to your question: a little code and a problem description. What have you tried so far? Where is the problem?

Comment: The project ist only a test project for multipeer connectivity. We want to safe incoming data to assign the device to the data later. We can not find an answer to our problem and have no idea how to handle it.

Comment: so for example there are three devices connected with multipeer connectivity. Everyone is sending an array and one device should evaluate them. To compare the arrays the device has to identify which array belongs to which device.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to pass along the user's name for the device you can import `UIKit` and access it by calling `UIDevice.currentDevice().name`.

Once you have that data, you can pass it alongside any other data when connecting with another peer.

This is how I pass string data back and forth between devices in a Swift 2 app:

```
try self.session.sendData((boolString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
```

Note that this example will be sending data to *all* peers that are connected to the session.

This example was lifted from [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/RF-Nelson/8a3e6319b0607cf6b181ae4ee00f6c4c) on using the Multipeer Connectivity framework.